# AppleScript error when trying to copy home folder to shared drive

Tags: macos, applescript

So, i'm working on a script that copies the home folder to a mounted shared drive folder. But i'm getting the following error:

> "Handler can't handle objects of this class number -10010"

This is the code I came up with following the example of other code i've seen on here. I'm guessing that it is the way i'm telling finder to duplicate.

```
set vserver to ("/Volumes/sharedfolder")
set source to ("/Users/user")

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate source to vserver
end tell
```

How else can I write this?

I've also tried running a boolean test to see if Finder saw the shared folder or my home folder and it retured false. (but only one false when it should have returned two)

```
tell application "Finder"
    setaBoolean1 to get (exists vserver)
    setaBoolean1 to get (exists source)

end tell
```

Comment: Notice in your original example script, you have `duplicate souce to vserver`: is that a typo in the web browser, or is it spelled `souce` in the original script too?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but related to what you are doing: I would suggest typing in `do shell script "rsync -azv " & source & " " & vserver` but without the `POSIX file` that NSGod suggests (because it is a terminal command and uses POSIX, unlike Finder), instead of the Finder block. This will ensure that all files are copied and that permissions are maintained (-a means archive). You can even run it multiple times to ensure that everything was copied, because it resumes broken transfers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set vserver to ("/Volumes/sharedfolder")
```

The line above sets the variable `vserver` to a `string` object consisting of `"/Volumes/sharedfolder"`. Likewise, the `set source to "/Users/user"` line sets `source` to a `string` object containing `"/Users/user"`. Note that strings are not what the Finder is expecting when you're telling it to duplicate items.

The tell app Finder line is basically trying to tell the Finder to duplicate one `string` into another `string`, which it doesn't know how to do (hence the `Handler can't handle objects of this class` message).

What you need to do is to, instead of creating strings, create some sort of file system reference to those folders, so that the Finder knows how to deal with them.

There are numerous ways to do this, but the method I found that works (which uses the same POSIX style path format) is the following:

```
set vserver to POSIX file "/Volumes/sharedfolder"
set source to POSIX file "/Users/user"

tell application "Finder"
    duplicate source to vserver
end tell
```

Comment: Getting warmer. Received another error "The operation can't be completed." number -36    Could this be a server issue. I was disconnected from the mounted server immediately after running the code.

Comment: forget that last comment, this works perfectly. I was just having connection issues at work.